# Do ConTeXt `product`s have isolated layouts?

Tags: context

Reading the docs, I came under the impression that products have isolated environments.

Experimentation suggests I misunderstand or am misusing them.  Given the following project structure:

```
entry.tex
  |- p1.tex
  |    \- p1-env.tex
  |- p2.tex
       \- p2-env.tex
```

Where `entry.tex`  includes two products (separated by a `\page`), I would expect `p1` to include the `p1-env` but not `p2-env`. However it appears that `p2-env.tex`, being the last to load, dominants any other styles.

A solution/workaround would seem to be just not use environments but rather have macros/commands that set the style accordingly, on demand.

However, if indeed all environments end up collapsing on the last-loaded environment, what's what's the point of the ConTeXt product-structure and environments?

Here's a sample starter that one can use to illustrate.

### p1-env.tex

```
\startenvironment *
      \setuplayout[
    leftmargin=0pt,
    backspace=9em,
    cutspace=3em,
    leftmargindistance=1em,
    leftedgedistance=1em,
    leftmargin=7.5em,
  ]

\stopenvironment
```

### p1.tex

```
\environment p1-env

\startproject *

  Hello from p1 \inmargin{Left}

\stopproject
```

### p2-env.tex

```
\startenvironment *
    \setuplayout[
    leftmargin=0pt,
    backspace=3em,
    cutspace=9em,
    rightmargindistance=1em,
    rightedgedistance=1em,
    rightmargin=7.5em,
  ]

  \setupmargindata[inmargin]
    [style=normal, location=right, stack=yes, distance=0pt]

\stopenvironment
```

### p2.tex

```
\environment p2-env

\startproject *

  Hello from p2 \inmargin{Right}

\stopproject
```

### entry.tex

```
% !TEX TS-program = ConTeXt (LuaTeX)    
\startproduct *
  \product p1
  \page  % Should reset layout.
  \product p2
\stopproduct
```

Comment: Shouldn’t `entry.tex` have `\start...\stopproject` and `p1.tex`/`p2.tex` the `\start...\stopproduct` pair?

Comment: @HenriMenke  Oddly enough, `projects` don't actually compile.  The inner `products` could be `components` but from looking at the source it looks like they were designed to be peers as well.  I stand to be corrected though. lol

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I notice is that you are using the ConTeXt project structure incorrectly.

But before we discuss that, let us take a look at environment scoping.  The general rule is:

> Environments do not have a scope.  Their definitions become active after calling `\environment` and cannot be “deactivated” after.

This is a very fundamental statement and is a consequence of the fact that `\environment` simply does `\input` under the hood.  Similarly, there is no mechanism in Plain TeX to “uninput” (or “deinput” if you like) a file.

Let me demonstrate this with a simplified version of your document structure:

#### `p1-env.tex`

```
\startenvironment *
  \def\foo{foo}
\stopenvironment
```

#### `p2-env.tex`

```
\startenvironment *
  \def\baz{baz}
\stopenvironment
```

#### `p1.tex`

```
\startcomponent *
  \environment p1-env
  {\tt\meaning\foo\par\meaning\baz}
\stopproject
```

#### `p2.tex`

```
\startcomponent *
  \environment p2-env
  {\tt\meaning\foo\par\meaning\baz}
\stopcomponent
```

#### `entry.tex`

```
\startproduct *
  \component p1
  \par
  \component p2
\stopproduct
```

Executing ConTeXt on `entry.tex` yields the following result:

[image]

You see that `\foo` remains defined even though we switch to a different file with different environment inputs.  The reason is exactly what I explained before.

You *can* work around this behaviour by explicitly introducing scoping with `\begingroup...\endgroup` (or `\start...\stop` in ConTeXt).  Keep in mind that this is not a good idea because TeX might run out of memory.  I don't know how likely that is and what the exact limits are but there definitely exist issues.

```
\startproduct *
  \start
    \component p1
  \stop
  \par
  \start
    \component p2
  \stop
\stopproduct
```

---

Next you noticed in a comment:

> Oddly enough, `projects` don't actually compile.

Yes, and the explanation is that projects do not define a valid `\starttext` ... `\stoptext` structure.  You can also see this from the log:

```
system          > invalid \starttext ... \stoptext structure
```

So the question is, what are projects actually?  The answer is that projects are collections of environment files.  Imagine you had a long list of environments for the page layout, the colour theme, the bibliography macros, and mathematical macros for your document.  You wouldn't want to repeat the whole list in every component, which is why you collect this list in a project.  For example

#### `proj-mag.tex`

```
\startproject *
  \environemnt env-design
  \environemnt env-layout
  \environemnt env-biblio
  \environemnt env-mathem
\stopproject
```

#### `p-issue1.tex`

```
\project proj-mag
\startproduct *
  \component c-editorial
\stopproduct
```

The file that you run ConTeXt on is `p-issue1.tex`.