# Reset heading style to default in ConTeXt

Tags: sectioning, context

After modifying a heading/title style with [`\setuphead`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuphead) per the [Titles](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Titles) instructions for mkiv, how might one reset that style to its default?

I had initially thought that the ConTeXt `environment` might do that, but [it appears not](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357347/1744).

If there's no inherent capability to restore styles, where would one find them in the source?

**EDIT** Example:

Given:

```
\setuphead[subsection][
  after={},
  align={flushleft, nothyphenated, verytolerant},
  alternative=text,
  distance=0pt,
  beforesection={},
  before={},
  inbetween={},
  textstyle={\tfx},
  interlinespace=-10pt,
  commandbefore={},
  commandafter={},
  aligntitle=float,
  number=no,
  strut=no,
  style={\tfx},
  command=\myHeadCommand,
]
```

Now, how does one reset all those settings to the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question; an example is needed. Here is what I consider an answer:

```
\setuphead [section] [color=red,style=bf]

\starttext

\startsection [title=Section One]

  Test

\stopsection

\setuphead [section] [color=,style=]

\startsection [title=Section Two]

  Test

\stopsection

\stoptext
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: So basically by setting the `var=` it resets to the default?  Because that'd be the answer. :)

Comment: If that's what you're looking for, yes, setting the `var` to an empty value resets to default.

Comment: Oddly, setting `distance=` causes an error for me (“Missing number, treated as zero”).  The others I have tried seem to work.

Comment: Assigning a empty value to a key doesn’t reset it, it just sets a different value which doesn’t have to be the original one. In case of the `distance` key empty values aren’t allowed and you have to use a dimension, e.g. `0pt`.