# Restrict \environment effects to single section

Tags: context

I'm working on something that really benefits from division into multiple files, and so am trying to figure out the Project/Product/Component structure. I do think I've got most of it working, except for some details in (ab)using the `\environment` feature: I'd like some components to use a particular environment, without affecting the rest of the document.

If I just put it at the beginning of the component, it doesn't unload and winds up affecting every component after this one in the product:

```
\startcomponent c_acronyms
\project proj_ref
\product prd_data
\environment env_list


\startchapter[title=Acronym definitions]

...

\stopchapter
\stopcomponent
```

I can hack together a solution using `\start` and `\stop`, but that feels rather ugly as far as hacks go, and any successive invocations of that environment are ignored:

```
\startcomponent c_acronyms
\project proj_ref
\product prd_data


\startchapter[title=Acronym definitions]
\start
\environment env_list

...

\stop
\stopchapter

\startchapter[title=Keeps default formatting]
\start
\environment env_list

...

\stop
\stopchapter
\stopcomponent
```

I get the feeling that I'm trying to use `\environment` for something it's not actually designed for, but what would the best replacement be for it? I imagine I could do something with modules, but that seems a lot heavier-weight than necessary for such a small collection of commands (especially in my Windows TeXLive installation, which doesn't seem to recognize modules in the project directory). Should I be putting together a specific `\definestartstop`?

For reference, here's the minimal contents of the rest of my hiearchy:

```
\startproduct prd_data
\project proj_ref


\startfrontmatter

\completecontent

\component c_acronyms

\stopfrontmatter
\stopproduct
```

```
\startproject proj_ref
\environment env_ref


\product prd_data

\stopproject
```

```
\startenvironment env_ref

\usepath[{data}]


\setupcolors[state=start]
\setupinteraction[state=start]


% Add thin spaces before tall punctuation
\definecharacterspacing[thin]
\setupcharacterspacing[thin][\number`:][left=.16667,alternative=1]
\setupcharacterspacing[thin][\number`;][left=.16667,alternative=1]
\setupcharacterspacing[thin][\number`?][left=.16667,alternative=1]
\setupcharacterspacing[thin][\number`!][left=.16667,alternative=1]
\setcharacterspacing[thin]


% Define look-and-feel for the document
\setupalign[hanging]
\setupindenting[yes,small]
\setupwhitespace[medium]

\definefontfeature[default][default][protrusion=quality]


\stopenvironment
```

```
\startenvironment env_list


% Override look-and-feel for tabbed lists
\setupindenting[no]
\setupwhitespace[big] % Makes the issue more obvious


\stopenvironment
```

And while I'm here, does anyone know *why* compiling the project file doesn't compile each of the products? I'd guess it was originally due to a restriction on one-output-per-invocation, but surely the switch to LuaTeX allows spawning child processes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do ConTeXt `product`s have isolated layouts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357347/)

Comment: This is similar to TeX's `\input`.  You cannot "deinput" the file afterwards.  You can only limit the effects by using grouping.  Unfortunately, ConTeXt keeps track of environment input globally (one the Lua level) which is why all successive attempts to use the environment are ignored.  So the closest you can get to your idea is removing the environment markers from the file and do `\start\input env_list ... \stop`.

Comment: Thanks! I do get why they aren't "deinput" (fun term) after the file, but it's a bit unfortunate that the environment loading is forced to be globally-unique; even if I had to make sure that the primary environment files overwrote everything in the specialized ones, I'd think it would be a lot more flexible if it were per-file.

And I did run a few searches, but apparently not with the right terms. Thanks for linking me to that as well! It's definitely similar, but I think I'm asking about an alternative (like `\input`) while that's wondering about use cases.

Comment: Actually, there is a difference between `\environment` and `\input` that makes the latter sub-optimal: since it doesn't know of the project directory structure, I need to use the full path relative to the component (`../env_list`). It definitely works for now, but hardcoding the path like that in an easy macro -- and, admittedly, not doing so is an easy fix -- seems like it's begging to break if I make enough environments to move them to a subfolder or if I nest a component even one level deeper than expected.

Comment: OT: Rather than using the `\catcode` hack, why not use `\frenchspacing` or `\newfrenchspacing` to get space before punctuation (or use the high-level interface `\setupspacing[fixed]` or `\setupspacing[packed]`.

Comment: I've just checked all of them along with `\setuplanguage[fr][spacing=packed]`, and none of them seemed to add the spaces before the punctuation, just changed the width of the space after it. Why something named after a rather recognizable style of typography doesn't actually set the most recognizable feature of that style is beyond me, though.

Comment: Just to be thorough, I also tried pairing the `\setuplanguage` with switching to `\mainlanguage[fr]` (it's not, I just like the look and don't have to worry too much about any traditional style). The quotation marks change and are spaced correctly, but the other punctuation remains unaffected

Comment: I've found it! `\setcharacterspacing[frenchpunctuation]` -- not actually documented anywhere on the wiki except the changelogs, but it is talked about on the mailing list (though I found it through the t-french module). The question is updated with what I'm using now, which isn't actually the builtin since I found those spaces a bit thicker than I wanted.

Comment: @WovenTales: You should document this on the wiki (so that your future self doesn't have to hunt around to figure out how this works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `\setups`.

```
\startenvironment env_list

% Override look-and-feel for tabbed lists
\startsetups[tabbled-list]
  \setupindenting[no]
  \setupwhitespace[big] % Makes the issue more obvious
\stopsetups

\stopenvironment
```

Then, input the environment in your project file and use

```
\start
\setups[tabbed-list]
....
\stop
```

to limit the region where you want to apply  setup. Some environments accept a `setup` key, so depending on how you are implementing the *tabbed list*, you could even pass `setups=tabbed-list` to an appropriate `\setup...` command.

Comment: That's probably the safest way of doing so, thanks! The "tabbed list" is just a literal sequence of macros from a `\definedescription` deriving from `tab`, so unfortunately it's not quite as simple as the best case you've given, but I can put it in a `\definestartstop` easily enough.

Answer (score 3):

You could write your own `\environment` wrapper which opens a group, inputs the environment file and ignores the `\start ... \stopenvironment` inside.

So if you have a file `env_test.tex`

```
\startenvironment *

  \def\envtest{Test}

\stopenvironment
```

you can do

```
\unexpanded\def\startlocalenvironment{%
  \dosingleempty\dostartlocalenvironment}
\def\dostartlocalenvironment[#1]{%
  \start
  \let\startenvironment\gobbleoptorarg
  \let\stopenvironment\relax
  \input{#1}}

\def\stoplocalenvironment{\stop}

\unexpanded\def\gobbleoptorarg{%
  \doifelsenextoptionalcs\gobbleopt\gobblearg}

\def\gobbleopt[#1]{}
\def\gobblearg #1 {}

\starttext

\startlocalenvironment[env_test]

  \show\envtest

\stoplocalenvironment

\show\envtest

\stoptext
```

On the command line I then get

```
> \envtest=macro:
->Test

...

> \envtest=undefined
```

Comment: There used to be a macro named `\startlocalenvironment ... \stoplocalenvironment`, but it did something different. A commented out definition is still in `file-job.mkvi`

Comment: Since this particular situation is so simple, I think I'll stick with @Aditya's `\setups` method for now. I'll definitely keep this in mind if I need a particularly complex environment, though! And just to point it out, there's a builtin version of `\gobblearg` mentioned on the wiki (on "System Macros/Handling Arguments"): `\gobbleoneargument`. Not sure how well it works for optional arguments, or even the standard ones, but it's there.

Comment: @WovenTales This version of `\gobblearg` is different from `\gobbleoneargument` (note the space after `#1`).

Comment: @Aditya You are right.  Looks more like some leftover from MKII, though.

Comment: Right. I was forgetting spacing has meaning in TeX. I'm too used to languages that only care about the tokens.